# Mobile devices converting + to &-#43; in URLs

Tags: html, url

I have a URL on a website that contains a + sign.  The format of the URL is

http://Path/page.aspx?ItemPath=%2fArg1+Arg2

Mobile browsers are converting the + sign to &#43; and it makes the pages not work.  If you are using Google Chrome (like I am) and you enter &#43; in your address bar, it will do a Google search for +.  If you open the Google page and enter &#43; in the search bar, it will bring up the same results but not change the search text from &#43; to +

I have done testing on an iPad 2 with iOS 5 installed and an Android cell phone with FireFox mobile installed and both of them are converting the + character in the URL to &#43;

This issue is very difficult to google

EDIT:
After doing some research I realized that the browser is converting the + to its ascii code

Comment: Are you encoding your URL?  If not, you should be.  This might solve your problem

Comment: The problem was solved by replacing the "+" sign in the link with a blank space.  This allows the browser to replace the " " with whatever it wants

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to delete the "+" sign and put a space in code instead.  The browser will automatically convert the space to the "+" sign instead of converting the space to the ascii code